# Django model post_save

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How do I insert new data to another models if the system detects the field is updated? for example i have two models **FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier** and **TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords**, this is the model

//FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier

```
class FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier(models.Model):
    Pending_Request = [
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Inactive', 'Inactive'),
    ]
    fmCustomerID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomer',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Customer")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    bodyTemperature = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    employee_number = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    inputdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    inputBy = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    modifyDate = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    modifyBy = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request, blank=True)
    def clean_name(self):
        return self.cleaned_data["employee_number"].upper()
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.employee_number = self.employee_number.upper()
        super(FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
   super(TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords, self).save(force_insert, force_update) //I just add this line of code

    @property
        def is_past_due(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return date.today() > self.modifyDate
```

//TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords

```
class TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords(models.Model):
    Pending_Request = [
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Inactive', 'Inactive'),
    ]
    fmCustomerID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomer',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Customer")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    bodyTemperature = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    employee_number = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    inputdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    inputBy = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    modifyDate = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    modifyBy = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request, blank=True)
```

Storyline:

the user updated the body temperature in **FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier**, i just want that in my models, i have a trigger when the system detect that the **FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier** updated, the record will insert in **TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords**.

this is the error i received

[image]

I hope you guys will help me with this problem. thanks

[image]

Comment: so do you want to create post save signal ?

Comment: yes, whenever the `FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier` is updated, the `TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords` will insert new data

Comment: I am confused how you are linking these two models?

Comment: As you can see, they have the same field, that is my way linking these two models,

Comment: if you have a suggestion or fixing the existing code fell free to change it. as long as the logic is the same

Comment: does having same fields gets model linked ? I have not learned that

Comment: what happens if you link these two models in one to one relation?

Comment: yes, I think so.

Comment: Or will it be a problem if you inherit FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier in TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords?

Comment: not a problem @daneilJames

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231446/discussion-between-user14823468-and-daneil-james).

Comment: has this solved your problem?

Comment: I just tried your answer but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I have done upto this for you.

```
class FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier(models.Model):
    Pending_Request = [
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Inactive', 'Inactive'),
    ]
    # fmCustomerID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomer',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
    # verbose_name="Customer")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    bodyTemperature = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    employee_number = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    inputdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    inputBy = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    modifyDate = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    modifyBy = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request, blank=True)


class TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords(models.Model):
    Pending_Request = [
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Inactive', 'Inactive'),
    ]
    fmCustomerID = models.OneToOneField(FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                                        verbose_name="Customer")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    bodyTemperature = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    employee_number = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    inputdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    inputBy = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    modifyDate = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    modifyBy = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(**kwargs)
        if not self.bodyTemperature:
            if self._state.adding:
                self.bodyTemperature = self.fmCustomerID.bodyTemperature
        super(TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


@receiver(post_save, sender=FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier)
def record_body(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(instance, 'trcustomeremployeesuppliersubmittedrecords'):
        tr_csutomeremployee = TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords(bodyTemperature=instance.bodyTemperature)
        tr_csutomeremployee.save()
```

Comment: Try migrating at first and save `FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier` you will automatically see body temprature being saved in 'TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords'

Comment: What did you do can you summarize?

Comment: first, i run makemigrations and migrate because of new field, and i copy the rest of the code youve added.

Comment: and in my database, i tried to update the FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier, but no data inserted in TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords

Comment: Once please delete your migration files and remigrate and import @ reciever decorater and once you create FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier you will see  TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords  being created and body temperature will be assigned

Comment: and the decorater should be outside model class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231449/discussion-between-user14823468-and-daneil-james).

Comment: i tried to print the `print(tr_csutomeremployee)` the value result is `None None`

Comment: lets continue in chat